# Shape of water drop on a wire

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-statics

Suppose a water drop falls on a wire of crossection A. If a drop of water is dropped on it, such that it dosent fall, what is the shape of the drop? Assume necessary parameters. I was wondering about this when i saw rain-drops flowing along a wire under gravity.
Also , is the shape different from that of a drop hanging from a flat plate?

Comment: The shape is something which you can easily observe (and probably have done so).  If you are asking for a *calculation* of the shape, what attempt have you made to do this yourself?  This site does not offer to do calculations or research for you to satisfy your curiosity.

Answer (score 1):

The shape of the drop will vary from spherical except where it touches the wire which will be parabolic curving into the wire. The point at which it begins to turn into a parabolic curve is dependent upon hydrophobic the wire material is.

This is because the predominant force is surface tension keeping the round shape. The secondary force is capillary action.

If the water is on an inclined wire, it will form a more classical teardrop shape due to adhesion.

Finally, gravity will also exert some force and the water drop will sag toward the ground until finally breaking from as per the famous pitch drop experiments.